# What are the rules regarding resewing Torah "sheets"?

Tags: halacha, sefer-torah, safrus

During my Yom Tov Torah reading, I noticed that two Sifrei Torah had seams that seemed (OK, a bit of a pun intended, here ;-) a bit loose. So, I have a few questions regarding some of the requirements regarding fixing the two sheets:

- Is there a minimal amount of margin space needed at the seam? Can two sheets overlap when stitching, and if so, is there a maximum or minimum amount?
- Can the corner of a sheet be cut completely (in its margin, of course) if it is frayed or if it makes restitching easier?
- If a strip of parchment is cut, does it have any *kedushah* or can it be discarded?

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer regarding the margins, from [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BvMTSFD73cUJ:https://torah.org/learning/shulchan-aruch-classes-chapter22a/%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us):

> There should be two-inch margins between consecutive columns (in
>   addition to space for stitching the sheets together and rolling the
>   first and last sheets on sticks; see Yoreh De'ah 278:2)

This implies that the sheets may "excessively" overlap each other as long as the margin width is maintained.